# ADF Copy Activity additional column on Source manipulating a value ($$FILEPATH)

Tags: azure-data-factory

Copy Activity with Source == Azure Blob and target == Azure Table.  Blobs use a wildcard file path.  The **$$FILEPATH** value can be set as an additional column but the value can not be referenced from dynamic content.  Or?  Would be awesome if the **$$FILEPATH** value could be split (hint hint using the **@split** function) and additional columns made from folders at certain depths.  Not finding any documentation how to reference values from dynamic content.  Tried to make a variable that references the value but that fails.

Playing with columns from the source is nice when previewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AFAIK**, `$$FILEPATH` in copy activity only gives the file path as a new column and copy activity didn't support manipulating the column values during the copy.

By Using Dataflows in ADF, you can achieve your requirement. But Dataflows didn't support Table storage as sink. So, the workaround in this case can be, first use the dataflow to manipulate the file path column and transform it to a temporary Blob file. After Dataflow activity, use copy activity to copy the temporary Blob file to Table storage.

In Dataflow give your source and give your wildcard path. Give the column name for the file path.

[image]

This will give the result like below in the data preview.

[image]

You can manipulate the column values in the dataflow using derived column transformation. Here, I used split for example.

[image]

In dataflow sink, give a temporary Blob file(Use output to single file and specify the filename in the sink options).

**My dataflow JSON for your reference:**

```
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "source_files",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "temp_files",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn1"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false,",
                "     rowUrlColumn: 'filepath',",
                "     wildcardPaths:['*']) ~> source1",
                "source1 derive(filepath = split(filepath, '/')[size(split(filepath, '/'))]) ~> derivedColumn1",
                "derivedColumn1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     partitionFileNames:['temp.csv'],",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     partitionBy('hash', 1)) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Use dataflow activity to execute this dataflow and after dataflow use copy activity like below.

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the time thanks with a data flow example.  Invoking a flow is magnitudes slower than the copy activity.  Same that values are poorly documented and can not be manipulated like other constants.  Ending up writing a console program rather than bending a flow and copy activity (and the performance is similar).  Anyways again appreciate the time taken and if Microsoft reads this please allow dynamic content on value references (and make the documentation more explicit).

Comment: You can submit your idea as a feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c)